# $\operatorname{Aut}(G)=S$ is non-abelian simple with $\operatorname{Out}(S)>1$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Suppose that $S$ is a non-abelian finite simple group with $\operatorname{Out}(S)>1$. The question is this: are there any non-abelian finite groups $G$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)=S$?

I am imposing the condition that $G$ be non-abelian so as to exclude having the obvious $\operatorname{Aut}(C_2^n) \cong \operatorname{GL}_n(2)$, which is simple for $n>2$. The condition $\operatorname{Out}(S)>1$ implies that $G$ cannot be $S$ itself.

Clearly, $G/Z(G) \cong \operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $S$, so either it is trivial (which is not allowed since $G$ is non-abelian) or $S$ itself. So a candidate $G$ must have the form $G=Z(G).S$ with $Z(G)>1$ (this notation expresses the fact that $G$ must be a non-split extension of $Z(G)$ by $S$). Thus the Schur multiplier of $S$ must be non-trivial.

Comment: $G/Z(G)\cong S$ but how to conclude $G=SZ(G)$?

Comment: First, is it clear why $Z(G)$ must be non-trivial?

Comment: it is definitely clear.

Comment: Ok. When I write $G=Z(G).S$ I am using Atlas notation. It means that $G$ is a non-split extension of $Z(G)$ by $S$, not a product.

Comment: I think it is better not to write in that form, which might me confusing here. Shur multiplier of simple groups seem to be known. Did you check https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/48af/62a7e2238952b419d8e2264e2ee464e08b41.pdf ?

Comment: Wikipedia has Schur multipliers too, but that doesn't solve the problem (which boils down to whether a quasisimple group can have a simple group as its automorphism group).

Comment: I think it is unlikely that there are such examples. $G$ cannot be the full covering group of $S$, since then we would get ${\rm Aut}(S) \cong {\rm Aut}(G)$. In fact the Schur Multiplier of $S$ would have to be non-cyclic to avoid this problem, and there are relatively few such examples.

Comment: @DerekHolt If you want, write this as an answer. (Consider putting in a few more details about these two claims you have made.)